# Change menu colour Dreamweaver CS6

Tags: colors, dreamweaver, adobe-cs6

I was wondering if it was possible to change the colour of the menu of Adobe Dreamweaver CS6?

I like to work with a black workspace, but Dreamweaver, as far as I know, doesn't seem to allow to do these changes. I know I can change code colouring and the background of the coding section, but I'd wish to change the entire interface.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. Just in Adobe Photoshop you can change the Work space Color. **Dreamweaver** CS6/CC **Work space Color Scheme** it doesn't has available in the "preferences" area and don't has the "interface" option. 
Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=np9j88df5gA
Or If you *use Adobe at night* use this for the brightness: http://www.nelsonpires.com/software/dimmer/